# How to draw line charts with complex data structures in d3

Tags: d3.js

I have the following complex data structure:

```
[
Object {id: 15, targets: Array[2]},
Object {id: 26, targets: Array[2]},
Object {id: 39, targets: Array[2]}
]
```

`'targets'` is an array of objects. Each of them has this shape:

```
Object {idTarget: "target1", events: Array[315]}
Object {idTarget: "target2", events: Array[310]}
```

`'events'` is an array with the real values to plot. 
So, each element has this shape:

```
Object {timestamp: 1373241642, value: 1801.335}
```

Now, with this structured dataset, I would like to create an svg group `'g'` for each external object (I am referring to 15, 26 and 39) and inside each group I want to create two lines, one for each target, using the values in `'events'`.

Having a flat dataset it's easy to proceed in the drawing following the pattern: select + data + enter + append, but I am having trouble with this complex dataset.

For example I don't even know how to assign a key function to start.

```
svg.selectAll('.element')
.data(data, function(d){ return d.id + ?})
```

I would like to have this kind of keys `'15target1', '15target2', '26target1', '26target2'` and so on.

Do you recommend to simplify the dataset giving up the possibility of having neat groups or there is a workaround here that lets me easily draw what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) for this. Your code would look something like this.

```
var gs = d3.selectAll("g").data(data, function(d) { return d.id; });
gs.enter().append("g");

var line = d3.svg.line().x(function(d) { return xscale(d.timestamp); })
                        .y(function(d) { return yscale(d.value); });
gs.selectAll("path")
  .data(function(d) { return d.targets; }, function(d) { return d.idTarget; })
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.events); });
```