# Impulse plot in d3

Tags: d3.js

I work with mass spectra and would like to generate dynamic spectral views for input spectra in d3, highcharts, nvd3, or some other visualization tool.

This is the type of line I'm looking for: [Impulse Plot example from Matlab](https://www.google.com/search?q=impulse%20plot&espv=210&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=9KcGU4PTNYjmoASIjIHwAQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=906#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=TijM2rOZRyB3SM%253A;QbNx2a6zp_U4LM;http%253A%252F%252Fwww.mathworks.com%252Fhelp%252Freleases%252FR2013b%252Fecon%252Fimpulse_ar1new.png;http%253A%252F%252Fwww.mathworks.com%252Fhelp%252Fecon%252Fcalculate-impulse-response-functions.html;560;420)

My data is pretty complex (embedded arrays like this question's... [How to draw line charts with complex data structures in d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829028/how-to-draw-line-charts-with-complex-data-structures-in-d3) ) and I can't get impulses like I was before:

```
var points = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("x1", function (d, i) {
    return xScale(d[0]);
})
    .attr("y1", function (d) {
    return yScale(d[1]);
})
    .attr("x2", function (d) {
    return xScale(d[0]);
})
    .attr("y2", function (d) {
    return yScale(0);
})
    .attr("class", "impulse");
```

As it turns out, I can't pull the embedded arrays up to the `.data` level, so I have to write this code a different way.  I was trying to follow the linked question and do:

```
var line = d3.svg.line().x(function(d) { return xscale(d.timestamp); })
                        .y(function(d) { return yscale(d.value); });
```

However, `d3.svg.line()` doesn't support the `x1,x2,y1,y2` I need.

I figure this nesting is going to do a lot for me, now, I just need a way to render my impulses.

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to have a single line per point (starting at the axis and ending at the point) with a line end marker.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Do you have any experience with plotting line svg classes in D3?  Is there another accessing routine other than the one I reference here?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "line svg classes", but SVG lines to require four coordinates to be set, so this is what you'll have to do. There are also paths, which are more general, but they won't really be easier to use in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In general, to achieve something like image you posted in Highcharts, you can use scatter series with properly created data: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/94/

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'scatter'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            lineWidth: 1,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            {x: 0, y: 0, marker: { enabled: false } }, // bottom point
            [0, 51.6],                                 // top point
            null,                                      // break line point
            {x: 1, y: 0, marker: { enabled: false } },
            [1, 59.0],
            null,
            {x: 2, y: 0, marker: { enabled: false } },
            [2, 49.2]
        ]
    }]
});
```